# Do any browser support WebRTC on ARM processors?

Tags: webrtc, chromium

I'm making a side project that uses WebRTC to do peer-to-peer video calling from a PC to some piece of dedicated hardware.

I'd really like to use a Raspberry Pi for my hardware prototype, but I'm having a hard time finding information on whether either of the main browsers (Midori & Chromium) supports WebRTC.

Can anyone offer any information?

Answer (score 2):

As of Today, 28th November 2014, **yes**

I use Iceweasel, with Rasbian. And it's work. You can use this website (https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/) to try your webcam from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As of Today, Sunday 19th May 2013

#### NO

http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream
[image]

#### NO

http://www.webrtc.org/

[image]

---

WebRTC is a stretch goal, in fact I would be very interested to find a browser supporting websockets and other HTML5 goodies. Another thing to bear in mind is codec licensing: http://www.raspberrypi.com/license-keys/

Answer (score 0):

For WebRTC for Raspberry Pi 2 there is [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/news/). It allows you to stream live Audio & Video from the Rpi to any browser on a PC (HTML5).